# PDFlib Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, pdflib

I'm trying to make PDFlib to work on wamp. I've downloaded http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-7/ and followed the installation guide ..

- I took the **libpdf_php.dll** and i copied it in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\ext (of course the proper version of libpdf )
- than i added in php.ini : **extension = libpdf_php.dll**

I've done this before and it worked fine, but after i changed my pc and my operating system  to windows 7 x64, I can't make it work I get this error in my log file :

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
>   library
>   'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.4/ext/libpdf_php.dll'
>   - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Any ideas ?

Comment: problem solved, I reinstalled wamp the 32 bits version (I had the 64 bits) and it worked without problems :)

Comment: am having the same problem and i have windows 7 64 bits, how can i know which version of wamp I have? 

Answer (score 2):

PDFlib is not supported in PHP/Windows-64 bit check the link http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-7/

Comment: Now proudly supported

Answer (score 0):

PDFlib offers the module for 32bit OS and 64bit OS for Windows respectively.
So you may check your module applied in your PC, whether it is for 32bit or 64bit.